# Arranging the elements in the diagram

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Using C# addin I was creating the elements and adding it into the diagram.So when we add to diagram it will not be arranged.So when I open the Diagram it will not be auto-arranged.So using Addin is there any Api provided by EA to auto-arrange all the elements created.

Comment: Unless you explain what you mean by "properly arranged" you will not get a reasonable answer (so I voted for closing due to "opinion-based").

Answer (score 1):

It is hard task to "properly arrange" 500 elements in diagram. If you are able to arrange elements using some of EA predefined layout styles, use LayoutDiagramEx method of Project Class. See http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/project_2.html

Comment: With the restriction that "properly arranged" is primarily opinion-based (the auto-layout is ok for smaller diagrams, but fails for any decent larger amount of elements).